# Implicit declaration of function 'ERR_load_crypto_strings' is invalid in C99 in Xcode

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, xcode

When Change Build System from Legacy to New Build System, above error occurred. My code is as following.

```
+ (NSString *) sign:(NSString*) dataString returnRaw:(BOOL)returnRaw{

    ERR_load_crypto_strings(); //Error Occurs in this line

    int retEr;
    char* text = (char*) [dataString UTF8String];
    unsigned char *data; 
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message tells you that the function isn't found.
To resolve it, you will need to add **#import** statement with the name of the header file in which the function is declared.

For example: `#import <openssl/ssl.h>` if it is in a separate framework, or  `#import "ssl.h"` if it is in the same package.